# Android Dev: Do things when App get started

Tags: android, oncreate, activity-lifecycle

im trying to implement a Sync process for my application. The internal sqlite database has to sync with the remote mysql database.
That works great, but now i want to implement, that always on app start the sync method gets called.
I simply put it in the onCreate() method but now the problem is, that everytime i go back from a further Activity with Intent, the sync method gets called.

Sorry for my bad english, i hope you guys understood.

Thanks in advance,
Joshua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can extend [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html), and sync your data in `onCreate()` in the Application class.

```
package com.your.package

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Sync data here
    }
}
```

Now open AndroidManifest.xml and find `<application>` tag. Change it to

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ...>
```

**Solution 2**

Create an SyncActivity, make it the first activity when app open. Sync your data here, and after that, open your original activity by

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SyncActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

The two flags remove this InitActivity from stack, so when users press back button, they will not go back to this activity.

Comment: Thats sounds really great & easy. I wanted to test that, but i got a little problem. I already have a sync Method in my MainActivity. From the Application Class i cant use that Method, is it a wise way just to copy & paste it?

Comment: Yes, I think it's ok. Let me know if you encounter any problem.

Comment: Thats awesome it worked now after some Errors. These erros where caused by a ProgressDialog & some Dialogs. It sounds logically for me that i cannot use a Toast or Dialog in Application, but is there a way that i can show it anyway?

Comment: You need an activity context to show dialog. Please check my update, if you still need the dialog.